# How to create element with absolute position

Tags: javascript, html

I want Date to appear above Second section. plz guide how to achieve it

```
    var sectionTwo = document.getElementById("sectionTwo");
    var x = sectionTwo.getBoundingClientRect();
    var b = document.createElement("div");
    b.style.position = 'fixed';
    b.innerHTML = new Date();
    document.body.appendChild(b);
    b.style.top = (x.top - b.style.height) + 'px';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlIec.png)

Comment: `b.style.position = 'absolute';`

Comment: its not working with any position

Comment: can you create a snippet demonstrates the problem

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlIec.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: As Bravo said, setting `position` to `absolute` **will** work. Then you set the `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `width`, and/or `height` (just some, not all). There are a couple of other clear issues with the code you've shown, in `b.style.top = (x.top - b.style.height) + 'px';`: 1. Elements don't have a `top` property, so `x.top` will be `undefined`. 2. You're using `b.style.height` but `b.style.height` has never been set, so it will be `""` (it doesn't provide the *computed* height, just the inline `height` style, which you haven't set).

Comment: an image isn't a snippet

Comment: ```b.style.bottom= 0;```&```b.style.position ="absolute"```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this:

HTML code:

```
<div id="sectionTwo">

</div>
```

JS code:

```
var sectionTwo = document.getElementById("sectionTwo");
var b = document.createElement("div");
b.innerHTML = new Date();
sectionTwo.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", b);
```

CSS code (just to for visualization):

```
#sectionTwo {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<div style="height:800px;"></div>
<div id="sectionOne">First Section</div>
<div id="sectionTwo">Second Section</div>
<button onclick="showDate();">toggle</button></div>



<script> function showDate() {
    var sectionTwo = document.getElementById("sectionTwo");
    var x = sectionTwo.getBoundingClientRect();
    var b = document.createElement("div");
    b.style.position = 'absolute';
    b.innerHTML = new Date();
    document.body.appendChild(b);
    b.style.bottom = 0;
    b.style.top = (x.top - b.offsetHeight) + 'px';
}</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmnex.png)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help you better.

```js
var sectionTwo = document.getElementById("sectionTwo");
var b = document.createElement("div");
b.innerHTML = new Date();
sectionTwo.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", b);
```

```css
#sectionTwo {

  height: 35px; width:35px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="sectionTwo">

</div>
```